# Convert app to use JWT

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, adfs

We have a Sharepoint on Prem app, that is authenticated/authorized via ADFS

ADFS returns SAML tokens. I would like to know if SP Server supports JWT's

Hopefully without custom code.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that it does not support JWT from ADFS in sharepoint 2016.

In SharePoint, it supports three types of claims providers:

1. Windows Claims. It is windows token.
2. Trusted Provider (SAML). It is SAML token.
3. Form Based Authentication.

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[Configuring ADFS Authentication on SharePoint 2016](http://www.dhavalcodes.com/Blog/Configuring-ADFS-Authentication-on-SharePoint-2016)

Comment: Thank you Amy. Is it possible to call an external API that is secured via JWT. Our SP environment is On Prem 2016 secured with ADFS/SAML developed using SPFx

Comment: we are also having this issue, also we do not want to do local token conversion from SAML to JWT to call external API